# Prestashop module technical review refusal

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I have acreated a prestashop module, and after passing the validation step in the module validator. I have submitted to the addons store .
Now I get this feedback, I don't really get it, and some of it doesn't really concern the module .
Do you have any proposal or suggestions ?
[Error Feedbakcs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2df91.png)

Since the module is well passed the module validator, So why it takes 20 days until I get the unusual feedback, which completely out of my hand .

Comment: shouldn't you be asking people from pretashop or this addons store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some issues there, but the message seems quite self explaining.

1. Enble the debug mode and perform a fresh install of your module, correct any errors, warnings, notices...
2. The "configure" button for the module is missing. It should be autogenerated if you use the function getcontent and set the module to configurable.
3. Remove the external links from your module, or contact PrestaShop in case they are mandatory.

There is also an attachment, lately they attach videos showcasing the errors so it's easier to find them.

Comment: Okey, sounds reasonable, Thank's, well appreciated .

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to mark the answer as solved if it has solved your doubts.